# Beginner Assembler Help

Tags: assembly, command

Can someone please explain in simple terms how the AND, SHL and CMP commands work? Thanks.

Comment: By how they work, do you mean what they do, or how they're implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND - One 0 bit means 0 as a result

```
1 And 0 = 0
0 And 1 = 0
1 And 1 = 1
```

5 AND 3
0101 AND 0011 (binary)

```
     0101
AND  0011
     ----
     0001
```

SHL - Shift Left

```
SHL EAX, 1 -> shift left one bit

SHL 5, 1 -> 5 is 0101 in binary, so if one shift left it becomes 1010(A)
```

CMP - Compare, it's general purpose and depends on cpu eflags.

```
CMP EAX,5
JE wherever   (if eax equals 5, the zero flag is set and jump is made)
```

Comment: So for example: move ax, 5 (next line) AND ax, 3 is what?

Comment: AND 5, 3 is like 0101 AND 0011 that equals to 0001

Comment: See this is where I get lost, how is that equal to 0001?

Comment: Do the Bitwise calculation as i told you above. Any 0 on either 5 or 3 (in binary) means 0 as a result. 0101 AND 0011. 0011 means that first 2 are 0s. From 0101, the third one is also 0. Then the last bits of 5 and 3 are both 1. Thus 1 AND 1 equals 1. In the end, 0001.

Comment: So you are telling me you can change a 5 into an A just by SHL by 1? When would you need to make that change?

Comment: Now that's a big story :) For instance, if you want to multiply by 2. Generally speaking shifts are used for many many purposes. One such purpose is cryptography. CRC also uses shifts. Many many reasons to use them that i can't really refer in a single comment.

Comment: This just blows my mind, if math was written in assembly code then 2 and 2 = 2 not 4!

Comment: Well, everything is based on definition. 2 + 2 is just a definition as well. You can read more on groups, rings(i suppose the english names are like that) etc if interested. AND is just a logic gate, as + is a defined math operation.

Comment: I am starting to think that I should have chosen graphic design instead of game programming, lol.

Comment: Just started my second year, love C++, hate assembly.

Comment: Love C++? `AND` is the same as `&`, `SHL` is the same as `<<` (when used with fundamental types, not with `cout`!), `CMP` when used with `JE`/`JNE` is like an `if` statement.